# C : Runtime Error Verdict (Help debugging)

Tags: c, debugging, runtime-error

I am working on a problem on an Online Judge ( link [here](http://a2oj.com/p.jsp?ID=22) ), and I keep getting a runtime error verdict each time I submit my solution. I have been looking at it for a while now, I still can't figure out what's wrong with it. I have also looked up the typical reasons behind a runtime error (arrays out of bonds, memory limit exceeded, logical errors ... ect). I can't find any of them in the code posted below :

```
#include<stdio.h>

int Hall[110][110];

int isValid(int x, int y){
int i,j,cnt=0;

for(i=x-1; i<=x+1; i++)
    for(j=y-1; j<=y+1; j++)
            if(Hall[x][y]==Hall[i][j])
                cnt++;  
if(cnt>1)
    return 0;
else
    return 1;
}

int notChecked(int N,int* checked,int size){
  int i;

  for(i=0; i<size; i++)
     if(checked[i] == N)
        return 0;

  return 1;
}

int main (void){
  int T,R,C,checked[110],i,j,k,size;

  scanf("%d",&T);
  for(i=0; i<T; i++){
    scanf("%d %d",&R,&C);
    //initialize
    size=0;
    for(j=0; j<R*C; j++)    checked[j] = -1;
    for(j=0; j<=C+1; j++){
            Hall[0][j] = -1;
            Hall[R+1][j] = -1;
    }
    for(j=0; j<=R+1; j++){
            Hall[j][0] = -1;
            Hall[j][C+1] = -1;
    }
    //read input
    for(j=1; j<=R; j++)
        for(k=1; k<=C; k++)
            scanf("%d",&Hall[j][k]);

    //algo:
    for(j=1; j<=R; j++)
        for(k=1; k<=C; k++)
            if(Hall[j][k]>=0){
                if(notChecked(Hall[j][k],checked,size)){
                    if(isValid(j,k)==0){
                        checked[size] = Hall[j][k];
                        size++;
                    }
                }
            }

    printf("%d\n",size);
}

return 0;}
```

Any help is much appreciated !

Comment: What happens if you run it yourself, and with what input?

Comment: @dbush It runs compeletly fine. I tried the input suggested on the problem's page, and came up with corner test cases myself such as a single cell grid (output should be 0), all cells of grid contain -1 (output 0)... Haven't tried the max input size though.

Comment: `int checked[110] ...for(j=0; j<R*C; j++)    checked[j] = -1;`  --> `checked[j]` out of bounds?

Comment: When they say "runtime error", does that mean the code exhibited an error, or that it took too long to run?  If it's the latter, you have some optimization to do.

Comment: @chux I just tried fixing that by setting the size of checked to 1100, the max value of R and C being a 100 for each. I still get the same verdict :/

Comment: @dbush Normally, if it took too long to run, I would get a Time Limit Exceeded verdict. Also, the time limit for the problem is 3 seconds (found at the bottom of the problem page), and considering the size of the input i don't think my code will exceed it. The program exhibits an error. Still need to find it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do bounds checking on your input.

According to the site `T` needs to be between 1 and 100 inclusive, so you need to check for that.  Then for each `R` and `C` (`N` and `M` on the site), they also need to be between 1 and 100 inclusive.

For each set of `R` by `C` entries, you need to make sure you actually read in `R` rows and `C` columns.  You also need to ensure that you read in `T` total sets of entries.

Comment: When a problem specification states a range for an input, I think it's intended as a guarantee, not something you're required to check.

Answer (score 0):

Problem Solved !

The code contained an array out of bonds problem, in the following line:

```
for(j=0; j<R*C; j++)    checked[j] = -1;
```

Knowing that checked had a size of 110 and R and C a max size of 100 each. I changed the size of checked to 10100 and it worked.

Thanks @chux for the help !